# Select columns periodically on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a Dataframe with `1116 columns`, how could I select just the columns in **a period of 17** ? 
More clearly select the 12th, 29th,46th,63rd... columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range` syntax:

```
cols = range(12, 1116, 17)
```

Then use this to feed `pd.DataFrame.iloc`:

```
df = df.iloc[:, cols]
```

Just remember that Python indexing begins at 0, so the first column with index 12 will be the 13th. This can easily be adjusted as necessary.

Comment: This doesn't give me the desired result. It multiplies every column *17 so it selects the columns 12*17, 13*17,14*17...1116*17 and this goes out of boundaries

Comment: That's not true. `list(range(12, 1116, 17))` returns  `[12, 29, 46, ... , 1066, 1083, 1100]`

Answer (score 0):

`df.iloc[:,[i*17 for i in range(0,65)]]`